# Use an attachment for both text/html and text/plain with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I'm using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files) to
send emails and I would like to have the same attachment for :
  * HTML version (`text/html`) as inline image (cid)
  * Text version (`text/plain`) as attachment

I'm testing the email with Mozilla Thunderbird 45.3.0 on Ubuntu.

I've have been playing around with `->setBody`, `->addPart`, `->embed` and `->attach` methods,
but I always broke one of the version (i.e. get the email in plain text either I view the message as HTML or Text).

My test code looks like (with valid SMTP address and file path of course) :

```php
function swiftMail() {
    require_once './vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
    //Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mail.com', 25);
    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        // Give the message a subject
        ->setSubject('SwiftMailer test // ' . uniqid('', true))
        // Set the From address with an associative array
        ->setFrom(array('first.name@mail.com' => 'Me'))
        // Set the To addresses with an associative array
        ->setTo(array('first.name@mail.com' => 'Me'));

    // attach the image as attachment
    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('./path/to/file.png')->setFilename('cool_image.png'));

    // set the email's body as plain text
    $message->setBody('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');

    // add the email's HTML part to the message
    $message->addPart(
        '<!doctype html>' .
        '<html>' .
        ' <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>' .
        ' <body>' .
        '  Here is an image <br />'.
        '  <img src="' . $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('./path/to/file.png')->setFilename('inline_cool_image.png')) . '" alt="Inline Image" /><br />' .
        '  Rest of message' .
        ' </body>' .
        '</html>',
        'text/html' // Mark the content-type as HTML
    );

    // send the message
    if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
    {
        echo "Failures:";
        print_r($failures);
    }
}
```

The following code result in two attachments (which could be fine) and only the plain text version available (which is not fine).

Is there a way to get attachments used as inline HTML image source and as standard attachment in plain text email ?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the exact same problem and was able to fix it by adding the plaintext part with `addPart()` instead of `setBody()`.

```
$message->addPart('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');
```

Based on your example, it would be:

```
function swiftMail() {
    require_once './vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
    //Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mail.com', 25);
    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        // Give the message a subject
        ->setSubject('SwiftMailer test // ' . uniqid('', true))
        // Set the From address with an associative array
        ->setFrom(array('first.name@mail.com' => 'Me'))
        // Set the To addresses with an associative array
        ->setTo(array('first.name@mail.com' => 'Me'));

    // attach the image as attachment
    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('./path/to/file.png')->setFilename('cool_image.png'));

    // set the email's body as plain text
    $message->addPart('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');

    // add the email's HTML part to the message
    $message->addPart(
        '<!doctype html>' .
        '<html>' .
        ' <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>' .
        ' <body>' .
        '  Here is an image <br />'.
        '  <img src="' . $message->embed(Swift_Image::fromPath('./path/to/file.png')->setFilename('inline_cool_image.png')) . '" alt="Inline Image" /><br />' .
        '  Rest of message' .
        ' </body>' .
        '</html>',
        'text/html' // Mark the content-type as HTML
    );

    // send the message
    if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
    {
        echo "Failures:";
        print_r($failures);
    }
}
```

Tested with SwiftMailer version 5.4.4, Thunderbird 45.5.0 on macOS and the Gmail web interface.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Boschman but still the same problem happens. When you fixed your problem, do you also have embedded / inline images in your HTML message ? When I remove the `$message->embed([...])` parts, everything is working as expected.

Comment: I just tested your example, and it works for me with addPart(). I used SwiftMailer version 5.4.4. I updated my answer with your complete example.

Comment: so do you confirm that you get "My amazing body in plain text" in the plain/txt message and not "Here is an image /n Inline image /n Rest of message" ? Just checked with the latest switfmailer and still get a transformation of the HTML content instead of the alternative text part.

Comment: When I use my example code my mail client shows me the html version of the body ("Here is an image..."). When I use your example code (with setBody) my mail client shows me the plaintext version of the body ("My amazing body in plain text").

Comment: Ok, maybe I misexplain what I wanted to do. I would like to have different content within the HTML or PLAIN email. A text transformation of the HTML won't match my need. For example, let's say I want to use a markdown content:
  * In the HTML content, pandoc is used to generate the email
  * In the TEXT content, the original markdown file is used
With Thunderbird, when I switch between Original HTML/Plain Text, I would like to see the different content. This is working as expected as far as I do not include embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `->setDisposition('inline')` to your Swift_Image

```
Swift_Image::fromPath('./path/to/file.png')->setFilename('inline_cool_image.png')->setDisposition('inline')
```

Comment: Thanks @jay-bryan-cañas already tried that and still only plain/txt email displayed regardless of the view options.